# Git keeps tracking undesirable files

Tags: git, visual-studio, gitignore

Morning
I had had a "project" composed of independent files, when I move it to visual studio the IDE creates lots of files which are useless to the repository. 
The Vs project is inside the git folder, got was not tracking that folder until my last commit

```
 C: repository/visualstudiofolder/anyvssubfolder
```

Now I have my `.gitignore` file with this line as I saw before C:

```
repository/visualstudiofolder/anyvssubfolder/
```

And I have use `git rm --cached C: repository/visualstudiofolder/anyvssubfolder`

It returns `a fatal:  C: repository is outside repository`, and keeps tracking those directories

I have tried on the ignore file and the remove command using `/` or `/**` at the end of the direction, still useless

How can I get rid of that directories?
I have push the changes to confirm it and all the undesirable files are now on the repo website

Comment: Use this gitignore for vs studio projects - [.ignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore)

Answer (score 0):

Try instead the same command executed from inside the repository:

```
cd c:\path\to\repository
git rm --cached -r visualstudiofolder/anyvssubfolder 
git commit -m "record deletion of visualstudiofolder/anyvssubfolder"
git status
```

The `.gitignore` should work, in the repo: `C:\path\to\repository\.gitignore`.

```
visualstudiofolder/anyvssubfolder/
```

Check that with:

```
cd C:\path\to\repository
git check-ignore -v -- visualstudiofolder/anyvssubfolder/aFile
```